# How to put the list of figures into a table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

How can I get a “list of figures” of the following type?

**List of figures**

[image]

Exactly, this list of figures is set as a table. I know this cannot be obtained by the command `\listoffigures` directly, but our thesis needs this format. I can get this type by making a real table and using cross referencing, but I prefer getting it with `\listoffigures` or other simple commands.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Do you load any packages which influence the list of figures? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I am sorry. I use '\documentclass{book}'. I just want to get the type talked above. It does not matter what documentclass is used. BTW, my english is very poor, so please forgive me for my syntax error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this one; the important code is between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \begingroup\let\addvspace\@gobble
    \raggedbottom\offinterlineskip\def\l@figure{\xiao@figure}\parindent\z@
    \hrule
    \vrule\vrule width \z@ height 1.2\ht\strutbox depth 1.2\dp\strutbox
    \makebox[\dimexpr3cm-0.8pt\relax][c]{\bfseries Number}\vrule
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-6cm}{\normalbaselines\centering {\large\strut}\bfseries Caption{\large\strut}}\vrule
    \makebox[\dimexpr3cm-0.8pt\relax][c]{\bfseries Page}\vrule
    \hrule
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \endgroup
    }
\def\xiao@figure#1#2{\xiao@figurei#1{#2}}
\long\def\xiao@figurei\numberline#1#2#3{%
  \vrule\vrule width \z@ height 1.2\ht\strutbox depth 1.2\dp\strutbox
  \makebox[\dimexpr3cm-0.8pt\relax][c]{Fig.\ #1}\vrule
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-6cm}{\normalbaselines\centering {\large\strut}#2{\large\strut}}\vrule
  \makebox[\dimexpr3cm-0.8pt\relax][c]{#3}\vrule
  \hrule
  \hskip-.4pt
  \hrule
  \nobreak
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption which is very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very
long}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The compiled example shows also a page break. Here I show only a small part.

[image]

---

Some comments about `\xiao@figure` and `\xiao@figurei`.

The entry in the `.lof` file for the first figure is

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Caption}}{1}
```

and `\contentsline{figure}` is first translated into `\l@figure`, according to the definition of `\contentsline`. Then, becauso of our redefinition of `\listoffigures`, LaTeX transforms `\l@figure` into `\xiao@figure`, so the main input becomes

```
\xiao@figure{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Caption}}{1}
```

The first argument to `\xiao@figure` is now

```
\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Caption}
```

and the second one is `1` (after stripping braces around arguments). Thus the next replacement is

```
\xiao@figurei\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Caption}{1}
```

and next the definition of `\xiao@figurei` is looked at: it has to be followed by `\numberline` (which is removed) and has three arguments

```
1.1
\ignorespaces Caption
1
```

and now the main part of the work can be done, because we have correctly identified the contents of the three table cells.

---

With `hyperref` the `\contentsline` macro has a different definition. Supporting links seems to be quite difficult, unfortunately.

In order to get a successful compilation (without links), you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\latexcontentsline\contentsline
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \begingroup\let\addvspace\@gobble
    \raggedbottom\offinterlineskip\def\l@figure{\xiao@figure}\parindent\z@
    \let\contentsline\latexcontentsline
    \hrule
    \vrule\vrule width \z@ height 1.2\ht\strutbox depth 1.2\dp\strutbox
    \makebox[\dimexpr3cm-0.8pt\relax][c]{\bfseries Number}\vrule
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-6cm}{\normalbaselines\centering {\large\strut}\bfseries Caption{\large\strut}}\vrule
    \makebox[\dimexpr3cm-0.8pt\relax][c]{\bfseries Page}\vrule
    \hrule
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \endgroup
    }
\def\xiao@figure#1{\xiao@figurei#1}
\long\def\xiao@figurei\numberline#1#2#3#4{%
  \vrule\vrule width \z@ height 1.2\ht\strutbox depth 1.2\dp\strutbox
  \makebox[\dimexpr3cm-0.8pt\relax][c]{Fig.\ #1}\vrule
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-6cm}{\normalbaselines\centering {\large\strut}#2{\large\strut}}\vrule
  \makebox[\dimexpr3cm-0.8pt\relax][c]{#3}\vrule
  \hrule
  \hskip-.4pt
  \hrule
  \nobreak
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I have some doubts about the definition of `\xiao@figurei` and `\xiao@figure`. `\xiao@figurei` has three parameters but `\xiao@figure` has only two. How to assign the two to the three?

Comment: @XIAOLishun I've added some explanation; TeX is a "macro expansion" language, so sometimes its workings are a bit obscure. :)

Comment: @ egreg Thanks a lot. I will study your codes for a moment in order to revise them for what I want. Maybe, there are also some questions for you. It is so nice of you.

Comment: @ egreg Well, there comes a problem again. After PDFLaTeX my .tex, there are some other generated codes. The LOF file includes the codes like `\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1--1}{\ignorespaces Logo of \TeX}}{4}{section.1.3}`. I do not want the code `{section.1.3}` because LaTeX warns me that "Use of \xiao@figure doesn't match its definition". I think the reason is `{section.1.3}`. How to realize this?

Comment: @XIAOLishun I've added a workaround; unfortunately, I couldn't add support for hyperlinks.

Comment: @ egreg It's OK. List of figures in a table is more important than hyperlinks. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17):

I want to provide an other approach. Therefor I am using the advantages of the core language `expl3`. The output will be created with `longtable`. So you can define your header and it allows page breaks.

First of all I want to give thanks to Joseph Wright for his improvements.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_listoffigures_storelines_tl
\DeclareDocumentCommand \mynumberline { m m }
    {
     \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {Figure~#1}
     \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {#2}
    }  
\DeclareDocumentCommand \mylatfigure { m m }
 {
     #1
  \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_listoffigures_storelines_tl
   {
     \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl \exp_not:N &
     \exp_not:V \l_tmpb_tl \exp_not:N &
     \exp_not:n { #2 \\ \hline }
   }
  }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \UseEntries {}
{
      \tl_use:N  \g_listoffigures_storelines_tl  
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter    
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr #1 \relax}}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \begingroup
    \let\l@figure\mylatfigure
    \let\numberline\mynumberline
    \let\addvspace\@gobble
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \begin{longtable}{@{}|C{2.5cm}|C{\linewidth-5cm}|C{2.5cm-6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}|@{}}\hline
     \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Caption} & \textbf{Page} \\\hline\endhead
     \UseEntries
   \end{longtable}%  
   \endgroup
   \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\listoftables
\chapter{foo}
Text
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{caption}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\addtocounter{page}{24}
\chapter{foo}
Text
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{The logo of \TeX}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\chapter{foo}
Text
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{Some figures of \LaTeX}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Of course you can combine the `expl3` part with the redefinition of `\listoftables` However I don't want to mix `expl3` with LaTeX2e-macros.

[image]

Comment: Very nice work; this has the advantage that the header is automatically repeated at page breaks.

Comment: Perfect! But I do not understand your code very well. I should learn more.