# Add column headings for ToC entries

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put the list of figures into a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52432/how-to-put-the-list-of-figures-into-a-table)
>   [Table of Contents modifications required](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73658/table-of-contents-modifications-required)

By default, the Table of Contents starts directly with content. However, we require the ToC page to have column headings such as s.no , title, page no. and so on.
How does one achieve this?

Default behaviour for ToC pages:

```
Contents
1 PROBLEM DEFINITION ...........................1
```

What I need to do:

```
Contents
srno chapter name.................................pgno
1    PROBLEM DEFINITION ...........................1
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do. Just show your "by default" case (in a minimalistic style) to give us something to start from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table of Contents modifications required](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73658/5764).